# my sql and java

Tags: java, sql

I am new to Java. I received an error in my project while compiling in Java.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>
> ```
> 'exit values('1234567','aaa','aaa','aaa','aaa','aaa',0)' at line 1.
> ```

[image: Screenshot of Code and Error]

Comment: Please include the complete query

Comment: please provide the neccessary code aswell

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question is not answerable because you omitted the code and SQL query involved in your problem.

Comment: In case no one else mentions it: please [edit] your question's title to something meaningful that relates to your question. Also, you should read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Try to change name of table 'exit' to some other value

Comment: For future and current reference: don't include an image of your code, include the actual (relevant) code copy-pasted from your IDE in a well formatted manner.

Comment: Thanx for such a fast reponse @Sree; @Kevin Esche;  @ Tim Biegeleisen...I will take care for next time @ Jonny Henly ...and really worked @ Rashid...Thanx ..thanx a lot ..

Comment: No, take care of it for THIS TIME, or your question will likely get closed.

Answer (score 2):

`exit` is a [MySQL reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) and is not allowed as a table name in SQL statements.

Rename the table, or if you really want to use this table name, then put it in backticks:

```
insert into `exit` values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Answer (score 2):

[Refer to this SQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html)

> An identifier may be quoted or unquoted. If an identifier contains special characters or is a reserved word, you must quote it whenever you refer to it. (Exception: A reserved word that follows a period in a qualified name must be an identifier, so it need not be quoted.) Reserved words are listed at Section 10.3, “Keywords and Reserved Words”.

[This StackOverflow answer exactly addresses your query as to how to use reserved words as an identifier.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23446378/6592474)